# Google Dataflow template BigQuery parameter value exception

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to run a google cloud dataflow job created using the "pubsub to bigquery" template, but no matter how I specify the BigQuery output table parameter, it always throws back the following exception on the job step that tries to write to big query:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Table reference is not in [project_id]:[dataset_id].[table_id]

I tried all the combinations (including brackets and no brackets) and I am certain the table exists (I can even query it using that format).

I wonder if anyone else faced a similar issue and was able to solve it.

Comment: Can you add some examples of the names you tried?

Comment: thanks @Daria, I used the following: 
[my-gcp-project:ds.mytable]
my-gcp-project:ds.mytable
[my-gcp-project]:[ds].[mytable]

Comment: my-gcp-project:ds.mytable looks correct. Dataset and table names are just letters and project name is letters and dashes, no other symbols?

Comment: Do you have more error messages since it should include the actual value of the table spec? Can you show some code samples regarding the BigQueryIO?